# Sass assigning variables by reference

Tags: css, sass, less

Let's take this example:

```
$a: red;
$b: $a;

$a: white;

body {
 background-color: $b;
}
```

This code compiles to:

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I was expecting the background-color to be white like in Less.

Is there a way to pass references when assigning variables in Sass ? Or is it the way the compiler behaves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar as what you want in using function :

```
$a: red;

@function b(){
  @return $a;
}

$a: white;

body {
 background-color: b();
}
```

Result :

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I read about it. It's just that we are migrating a large project from Less to Sass, and that would make a huge change. However, we could run a regex on all files to change variables to function calls. We'll look into this solution.